# Send custom info with WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have the following problem:
i need to send some custom info with every request made by a WebBrowser control. For example one of the infos is the used app version.

Now i have already read here that it is impossible to set custom headers for a WebBrowser control.

I have already tried to intercept all requests and perform them on my own with a WebClient (or HttpWebRequest). It partially works but is very buggy and often throws errors.

Any other ideas how to send the custom infos with every request that is made by the WebBrowser control?

Comment: I think intercepting the requests is your best bet. If you post the code you use to do this maybe you can get some help making it stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the web server you are interacting with your own? Could you just add a query string parameter for all the data you want? Something like

```
http://yourwebsite/YourPage.aspx?version=2
```

Then you'd be able to process it on the server, either during that request in the aspx page, or via the logfiles for the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that as you can't modify the content that gets sent directly from the WebBrowser and that intercepting every call and acting as a proxy for every request, while still maintaining all browser functionality may be too cumbersome.

Instead I'd suggest sending an additional request with just the additional information you want to record every time you make a request.
That could lead to a lot of overhead so it might be easier to send this once and then pass a hash of it, or some other identifying key to the webpage (as a querystring parameter) on the first request so it can reconcile the 2 pieces of information. Assuming that you are in control of the web server you could then have the web server set that hash/key as a cookie so it would be passed again with subsequent request from the control.